# Stdin to file, terminate with new line, using cat?

Tags: linux, shell, sh, posix, stdin

Background

Two containers are needed to be unlocked by the same passphrase. I plan to save the passphrase in a variable and reuse it for both containers. They are unlocked by different script files. So I actually have to save the passphrase into a file (or more securely, into a named pipe file) for sharing it between the scripts.

I have problem while reading the passphrase from user keyboard input (stdin).

By default `read` trims leading and trailing spaces and tabs. For passphrase we need to retain them as what user input is. I can tweak the `IFS` so it keeps spaces and tabs.

```
OLD_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=
read -r passphrase
IFS="$OLD_IFS"
printf -- '%s' "$passphrase" | hexdump -C         # debug
printf -- '%s' "$passphrase" > /tmp/namedpipe &
unset passphrase
```

Other than the fifth line is extra for debugging, there are six lines of code. We have to unset the variable afterwards too. If we can achieve it by `cat`, it would be more concise.

```
cat > /tmp/namedpipe
```

However, pressing `Enter` does not terminate the input. It can only be terminated by `Ctrl+c`. By pressing `Ctrl+c`, we actually terminate the entire program.

How to terminate stdin by `Enter`, using the `cat` command?

Comment: If you mean "using _only_ the cat command", this is impossible (given only the capabilities present in standardized or widespread versions of `cat`). If you just mean "using the `cat` command in some way", it's an unnecessary extra piece, because something other than `cat` will be doing all the work.

Comment: BTW, `IFS= read -r line` makes it unnecessary to mess with `OLD_IFS` at all. When you set `IFS=` _as part of the same command_ as the use of `read`, the change to its value is scoped to only that one `read` command and doesn't apply to anything happening later.

Comment: That said, I don't understand why you're using a named pipe here in the first place. Why not fork off both scripts after reading the password in a shared parent process? If each process is a forked subshell instead of an exec'd subprocess, you don't even need to export it into the environment.

Comment: BTW, think about the existence of `password=$(head -n 1 | tee /tmp/namedpipe)` -- you're reading exactly one line in, and writing it both to your named pipe and also to stdout where it gets captured into a variable; can of course just use `head -n 1 >/tmp/namedpipe` if you _don't_ need any other copy.

Comment: (a named pipe _in `/tmp`_, btw, opens you up to races where someone tries to get their own symlink in place before your script starts so they can collect the password instead of you; you should be choosing a directory that's owned only by the individual user)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can't you avoid that race condition just by checking `stat` right after `mkfifo`?

Comment: I think it is not possible to read the pwd in the shared parent. When child one reads the pwd, it validates it. Ask again if it is incorrect. The final correct pwd is saved and passed to the second child, through the named pipe. I prefer named pipe over a regular file to avoid pwd appeared on the disk.

Comment: Why not make use of the return value from the child to know if the password entered was correct or not and simply loop until the supplied password was correct (or some max number of attempts were made)? That would allow you to use a parent process for that purpose, asking for the pass in the parent and using the return from the child to know if it is correct.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, the only problem I see with that is if we want to run both children in parallel, we wouldn't want to wait to start the second child until the first has finished. But this is definitely doable -- could f/e use a signal handler to let the first child tell the parent that validation was successful, or have the first child fork the second one at that point, etc.

Comment: @JosephSible that's a fair bit of work, though, and nonportable work at that (with `stat`'s usage and output formatting not being standardized by POSIX and thus varying across platforms).

Comment: Thank you Charles Duffy, Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica, and David C. Rankin. Your ideas are all great. Actually I am modifying (as less as possible) the Dracut initramfs to take one pwd for two LUKS devs. So forking from the parent process (init) would need a total rewrite. Asking pwd in parent (init), taking return values from children (sbin/cryptroot-ask) is possible. However in the child there are a lot more other codes. I would need two more env vars to control and skip them. It may mess things up. But this approach avoids the racing condition of (fifo) files. I am still considering.

Comment: Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica. Thanks for the reminder. If I am going for the fifo route, I will check the stat for added security.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Thank you very much. `head -n 1` seems to be the thing I am looking for. But for some reason I failed to get it working. It also blocks even after I hit `Enter`. My code: `mkfifo /tmp/namedpipe ; head -n 1 > /tmp/namedpipe ; echo 'asked' ; secret="$(cat /tmp/namedpipe)" ; echo "$secret" ; printf -- '%s' "$secret" | hexdump -C ; rm -vf /tmp/namedpipe`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Almost fell over when I saw [Universal Unix tool AWK gets Unicode support](https://www.theregister.com/2022/08/23/universal_unix_tool_awk_gets/?utm_source=daily&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_content=article). Times they are a changing... (I like the way the article opens `:)`

Comment: @midnite, ...I do urge you to put your FIFO in a directory that doesn't have `+t` permissions (and isn't writable by users other than the intended one), mooting the need to stat it to check that it's really yours. Modern Linux distros typically have a per-user location for transient or temporary files under `/run`; one of the `XDG_*` environment variables will point to it; but even `mktemp -t -d` to create a directory owned by your own account under `/tmp` and putting the FIFO _there_ is a cleaner solution.

Comment: @midnite, the code you pasted above does the write first and the read only after the write is done. They have to happen at the same time; attempting to write to a FIFO blocks until there's a reader attached, and the inverse.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read only one line of input, instead of `cat`, use `head -n 1`.

Thus: `head -n 1 >/tmp/namedpipe`; or, to keep your debugging, `head -n 1 | tee /tmp/namedpipe | hexdump -C`

---

By the way -- you don't need to clear IFS *before starting `read`*; you can clear IFS only for the one command by making `IFS=` part of the same command, instead of a prior command.

```
                  # no reason to store old IFS
IFS= read -r line # change only lives while read is running
                  # no reason to restore old IFS
```